# xml transform into another xml

Tags: xml, transformation

I have a large xml file with this format

```xml
<data>
<chars>
<prod>162</prod>
<atr>Brand</atr>
<value>Sony</value>
<filter>1</filter>
</chars>
<chars>
<prod>162</prod>
<atr>Type</atr>
<value>Camera</value>
<filter>1</filter>
</chars>
<chars>
<prod>162</prod>
<atr>Color</atr>
<value>yellow</value>
<filter>1</filter>
</chars>
<prod>163</prod>
<atr>Brand</atr>
<value>Philips</value>
<filter>1</filter>
</chars>
<chars>
<prod>163</prod>
<atr>Type</atr>
<value>Monitor</value>
<filter>1</filter>
</chars>
....
</data>
```

that in excel gives the table below:

```
Prod Atr    Value   Filter
162  Brand  Sony    1
162  Type   Camera  1
162  Color  Yellow  1
163  Brand  Philips 1
163  Type   Monitor 1
```

I want to transform the above xml in a xml format in order to take this table (exclude the column filter):

```
Prod  Atr1   Value1   Atr2  Value2   Atr3   Value3
162   Brand  Sony     Type  Camera   Color  Yellow
163   Brand  Philips  Type  Monitor
```

or better result

```
Prod  Brand   Type   Color
162   Sony    Camera Yellow
163   Philips Monitor
```

This file has 30000 lines and every product has different number of attributes. For example product 162 has 3 attributes but product 163 has 2 attributes. If it is possible i want the transformation to be outside the excel (in a linux environment if i set a cronjob)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think of bash with Xmlstarlet!

Answer (score 1):

Try this XSLT 3.0 transformation:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <data>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="/data/chars" group-by="prod">
        <chars>
          <xsl:copy-of select="prod"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:element name="{atr}">{value}</xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
       </chars>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
    </data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <chars>
      <prod>162</prod>
      <Brand>Sony</Brand>
      <Type>Camera</Type>
      <Color>yellow</Color>
   </chars>
   <chars>
      <prod>163</prod>
      <Brand>Philips</Brand>
      <Type>Monitor</Type>
   </chars>
</data>
```

which hopefully gives what you want when imported into Excel. See it in action at

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbeF

(I had to correct your data to make it well-formed XML)

Comment: Thank you very much mr. Michael Kay. But now i see that in my file i have many atributes that contain special characters eg. Type Of Machine (the spaces between). So if we transform to an element then then process will stop with errors. How can i replace the invalid characters with xsl?. I saw that the file contain spaces, parenthesis and /.

Thanks once again!!!

Comment: You could replace the characters using the translate() function, or you could abandon the idea of using the property names as element names, and generate (say) `<property name="type of machine">Monitor</property>` instead. But that might not import so nicely into Excel.

Comment: The problem solved with this function: <xsl:element name="{replace((atr), '[^a-zA-Z.]', '_')}">{value}</xsl:element>. Thanks Again for your HELP!!!